# e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("IdVoiture") is returning 'nothing'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

i have a rad grid which contains a view column allowing me to see details in a new window.
i am adding to that button in code behind a onclick attribute.
this is my code of the radgrid_itemCreated:

```
If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then            

        Dim btn As Button
        btn = e.Item.FindControl("btnView")
        Dim s As String = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("IdVoiture")
        btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OpenViewRepport('" + e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("IdVoiture") + "','4'); return false;")
End If
```

my problem is that 
e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("IdVoiture") is returning nothing.
if u have a solution please help!!

Comment: i solved my problem, first of all the "e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)" itself returned the carid because it is the datakey of the radgrid.
second of all to set the onclick property of the button, the fonction 
" btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "script();")  "  didnt work for me , i just had to put btn.onclientclick= "script();"

all though all the sites and forums say that  btn.Attributes.Add("onclick","string") is the right way, i found this as the only solution that worked for me .

Comment: both are the same thing, asp will render the onclick attribute from the OnClientClick property value anyway.